# how to filter all the request through custom filter in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to springs so help me out....
I need to know the web.xml configuration to filter all my request through a custom filter....

i.e

This is my normal web.xml

```
     <servlet>
 <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
```

now what changes should i make to my web.xml so that all my requests pass through custom filter...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a `javax.servlet.Filter`, the configuration is as follows in the `web.xml`.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>custom-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>your.filter.type.MyFilter</filter-class>
    <!-- Other options -->
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>custom-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <!-- Other options -->
</filter-mapping>
```

You can read all the configuration options [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1015950).

Comment: should i replace DispatcherServlet mapping with this one or should i keep both with same url pattern ?

Comment: @user3091495 If you want your `DispatcherServlet` to handle all requests use `/*`. If you want the `Filter` to filter all requests, use `/*`.

Comment: @user3091495 This is a servlet issue, not a Spring issue. The `<url-pattern>` element specifies on which urls a `Servlet` or `Filter` should be applied. Read the linked document.